# BadRAM Range: cannot set up the right range

Tags: grub2, ram, memtest, badram

I think my MacBook with soldered RAM has a RAM issue. 
With memtest86+, I figured out which BadRAM pattern I have,
but I cannot interpret the result correctly. 
How should I read the range to set up the right exclusion in GRUB?

Here are my memtest results:

```
BadRAM Patterns
---------------
badram=0x0000000058cb4000,0xfffffffffffffc00,
       0x0000000058cb4400,0xfffffffffffffc00,
       0x0000000058cb4800,0xfffffffffffffc00,
       0x0000000058cb4c00,0xfffffffffffffc00,
       0x0000000058cb5000,0xfffffffffffff800,
       0x0000000058cb5800,0xfffffffffffff800,
       0x0000000058cb6000,0xfffffffffffff800,
       0x0000000058cb6800,0xfffffffffffff800,
       0x0000000058cb7000,0xfffffffffffff800,
       0x0000000058cb7800,0xfffffffffffff800
```

<sup>[Manually transcribed from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDj0h.jpg).]</sup>

Would `memmap=64K$0x58cb0000` be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can try it.

Check `/proc/cmdline` to see if it's passed correctly, to make sure Grub doesn't mess with the `$` characters, otherwise add `\` escape characters.

There is also [badram support in Grub](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#badram) (GRUB_BADRAM in /etc/default/grub if you use `grub-mkconfig`). However it's also necessary to test whether it's effective.

The reserved range should show up in `/proc/iomem` (ranges shown only for root).

Another option, if your kernel has `CONFIG_MEMTEST=y`, is to try `memtest=17` parameter. Then check `dmesg` for test results, and `EarlyMemtestBad` in `/proc/meminfo`. This way the kernel tests memory every time you boot up and automatically reserves bad ranges on its own.

However, this only works if your RAM is faulty in a certain way that is always detected reliably. It would also slow down the boot process some. (The kernel only does a simple pattern test, which takes a few seconds).

You can also test memory in userspace using `memtester`.

Comment: Thank you very much, so far so good. Is my Grub_Badram is correct defined here? GRUB_BADRAM="0x58cb0000,0xffffc000"

Comment: You'd have to re-run grub-mkconfig afterwards, and then still verify in /proc/iomem that it shows this region as reserved (the memory regions are also printed in dmesg).

Comment: I did the /proc/iomen check as root. I see a couple lines which are tagged as "Unusable memory" but one specific line has written "58cb400 - 58cb7fff: Unusable memory". I think that should be correct one to exclude the bad patterns or?

Comment: Yes, that should be it.

Comment: Thank you very much frostschutz and "Danke"